# Selecting latest message per thread

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table (**messages**) with the following columns

message_id (**pk**), thread_id, message_body, date_posted, posted_by,....

How can I select the latest message per thread with the results in descending order according to date_posted?

sample table

```
-------------------------------------------------
message_id  |  thread_id  |  body |  date_posted  
-------------------------------------------------
1           |  1          |  ...  |  2016-06-03
-------------------------------------------------
2           |  1          |  ...  |  2016-06-04
-------------------------------------------------
3           |  2          |  ...  |  2016-06-05
-------------------------------------------------
4           |  1          |  ...  |  2016-06-06
-------------------------------------------------
5           |  2          |  ...  |  2016-06-07
-------------------------------------------------
6           |  3          |  ...  |  2016-06-08
-------------------------------------------------
7           |  2          |  ...  |  2016-06-09
-------------------------------------------------
```

expected result

```
-------------------------------------------------
message_id  |  thread_id  |  body |  date_posted  
-------------------------------------------------
7           |  2          |  ...  |  2016-06-09
-------------------------------------------------
6           |  3          |  ...  |  2016-06-08
-------------------------------------------------
4           |  1          |  ...  |  2016-06-06
-------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: You should post some sample table and expected result.. Moreover the sql query which you tried so far.

Comment: @Ullas finished adding an example

Comment: @CzarJohnDemafeliz you can get this using inner select query and then group by

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this;)

```
select t1.*
from messages t1
inner join (
    select max(date_posted) as date_posted, thread_id
    from messages
    group by thread_id
) t2 on t2.thread_id = t1.thread_id and t2.date_posted = t1.date_posted
order by t1.date_posted
```

Or you can use `in` :

```
select *
from messages
where (date_posted, thread_id) in (
    select max(date_posted) as date_posted, thread_id
    from messages
    group by thread_id
)
order by date_posted
```

[**SQLFiddle DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ab1d9/2)

Comment: I used the second one and I achieved my expected results when I added ORDER BY date_posted at the end

Comment: @Ullas Yes, didn't notice that.:-)

Answer (score 1):

you can do it like this

```
SELECT thread_id,message FROM  (Select *  from messages   ORDER BY thread_id,latestDate DESC) r group by thread_id;
```

Comment: first you have to order by it using threadid and date (within inner query) and then you can group by it

Comment: you have a double order by (typo) there

Comment: i do not know where you got latestDate

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM messages GROUP BY thread_id ORDER BY  date_posted DESC;
```

Comment: this will not work because execution order of mysql is  :: 
WHERE clause
SELECT clause
GROUP BY clause
HAVING clause
ORDER BY clause

Answer (score 0):

Just an other perspective by giving a row number based on the thread_id and date_posted in descending order.

**Query**

```
select t.message_id, t.thread_id, t.body, t.date_posted from( 
    select message_id, thread_id, body, date_posted, 
    (
        case thread_id when @curA 
        then @curRow := @curRow + 1 
        else @curRow := 1 and @curA := thread_id end 
    ) as rn 
    from messages m, 
    (select @curRow := 0, @curA := '') r 
    order by thread_id, date_posted desc
)t
where t.rn = 1
order by t.date_posted desc;
```

### [**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/47a94/2)

Comment: @10086 : I don't have a `group by` clause to use `having` clause.